# What is None argument in sql clause in UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, sql, where-clause, cursor

I have a bit of code that is a groupby iterator.  It works well, and I understand most of it, but I am wondering what the None argument does within the sql_clause in the code below.  I know this is probably a really simple explanation and I have seen this in other SQL clauses as well, but have not been able to find a good explanation of why it is needed.  Below is my snippet of code:

```
case_fields = ["unique_id", "ELCODE", "SeasonCode"]
max_field = "PERCENTAGE"
sql_orderby = "ORDER BY {}, {} DESC".format(",".join(case_fields), max_field) 

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(intersect, "*", sql_clause=(None, sql_orderby)) as cursor:
    case_func = itemgetter(*(cursor.fields.index(fld) for fld in case_fields))
    for key, group in groupby(cursor, case_func):
        next(group)
        for extra in group:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

Just looking for an explanation or a source that describes what the None argument does within the UpdateCursor where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm#S2_GUID-5CBF0F12-3B31-41AC-A525-65829523F692) help page outlines what the `None` does in the syntax section.  `None` is Python for `Null` - it does/passes nothing.

> An optional pair of SQL prefix and postfix clauses organized in a list
>   or tuple.
>
> SQL prefix supports None, DISTINCT, and TOP. SQL postfix supports
>   None, ORDER BY, and GROUP BY.
>
> An SQL prefix clause is positioned in the first position and will be
>   inserted between the SELECT keyword and the SELECT COLUMN LIST. The
>   SQL prefix clause is most commonly used for clauses such as DISTINCT
>   or ALL.
>
> An SQL postfix clause is positioned in the second position and will be
>   appended to the SELECT statement, following the where clause. The SQL
>   postfix clause is most commonly used for clauses such as ORDER BY.
>   Note:
>
> DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and ALL are only supported when working with
>   databases. They are not supported by other data sources (such as dBASE
>   or INFO tables).
>
> TOP is only supported by SQL Server and MS Access databases.
>
> (The default value is (None, None))

You have the option of passing a SQL prefix or postfix as part of your SQL query.  Something like a `SELECT DISTINCT` or a `SELECT TOP`.  What you are doing with the `None` is just passing `SELECT` without any other modifier.

So instead of:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 *
```

you are using

```sql
SELECT *
```